# Stop Google Search Opening in Chrome

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, firefox-for-android, google-search

Until recently when I used the default Google search bar and tapped a search result it would open in Firefox. However there must have been an update to either the search bar or Firefox as the results are now opening in a stripped down Chrome window.

This is happening on both my devices (Moto G - 6.0 and Nexus 7 - 6.0.1). Firefox is set to open multiple tabs and other apps (mail and Feedly) continue to open in Firefox.

How can I force the search app to open the results in Firefox rather than Chrome?

Comment: Perhaps disable Google chrome?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google Search uses Chrome Custom Tabs since April 27, 2016. From [9to5Google](http://9to5google.com/2016/04/27/google-chrome-custom-tabs/),

> After its most recent update, the Google app now opens search results as Chrome Custom Tabs. [...]
>
> [...]. By default, links from search results now open as a Custom Tab that features a blue action bar with options to Share, Copy link, Find in page, and Open in Chrome.

To change its behavior,
open *Google app*'s setting by e.g. tapping *Google app* from app launcher to navigate to Google Now screen, tap hamburger icon (3 horizontal bars) on top-left to open navigation drawer, then,

> Users can go to Settings > Accounts & privacy to toggle off the new ‘Open web pages in app' option if they prefer opening all links the old way.

---

Related: [Prevent apps opening links in Chrome Custom Tabs (i.e. open in default browser directly)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145745/prevent-apps-opening-links-in-chrome-custom-tabs-i-e-open-in-default-browser-d)