# I don't want ANY action to take place within the Google Now launcher for default browser

Tags: chrome-for-android, default-applications

This seems to be a totally unanswered topic, please enlighten me but...

I don't want ANY action to take place within the Google Now launcher for default browser. I simply want to click on the search box and have it display results for me within Google. I can't get it to stop "asking" for a browser or going to Chrome or going to the default browser. Why can't I simply turn this off?

The default browser constantly pops up unrelenting, not allowing me to use my Google card settings, and simple search box.   If I set a default browser, it will actually launch Chrome right out of the Google app, not allowing a simple search within the app.

Going into privacy and turning off "Open web pages in app" does not work, it still opens Chrome. There must be a way, beacuse essentially Google Now cards is useless and the Google Widget is useless, because it always opens Chrome under all circumstances.

Similar to [Stop Google Search Opening in Chrome](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146149/stop-google-search-opening-in-chrome/185390)

Comment: I don't understand what result you expect.  What do you mean by "display results for me within Google." ?  What do you mean by Google in this context?  Of course the results of your search are going to open a web browser, how else are you going to see web search results?

Comment: On my android, I have the Google app, widget and Cards installed.   When I do a search within cards it actually does a search within the Google app itself, and does not launch a browser, or tab.    The problem is that once a search displays the results it immediately launches a Chrome browser/tab with the exact same search and shows it there.

Further, when in settings for Google cards add-on, I go into settings and it constantly pops up asking for which default browser to use.  When instead I just want to edit settings.

Comment: If I have some unique problem, perhaps thats why I can't find any answers on this.   I can offer a video, if there was a way to take a self video on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

> Going into privacy and turning off "Open web pages in app" does not work, it still opens Chrome.

Actually make sure that setting is on being that you want it to open in the Google app

Then go into settings>manage apps. Open chrome, Google now, and any other browser apps and clear their defaults.

If that doesn't help, clear data of the Google app.

Comment: These are great suggestions, I didn't before do them in that exact sequence.  However, it didn't solve my problem.   I cleared not only cache, but all Google data i.e. losing all settings, I uninstalled Now launcher, cleared all default of open apps even rebooted phone.

With generic config and new settings, when entering the Google app, I am presented with the slide up dialog "what browser to use".    Its like something, maybe not even Google is forcing a decision to a browser open.

Comment: Its back to Now launcher cards in Google which is stable, until I go into Settings.   This itself launches the slide up window, asking for a browser.   The only way to manage this is I installed "Better open with" and it allows a 5 sec gap to choose things.   The only thing I cannot seem to do, is get the system from asking for that prompt.

The "Open web pages in app" does react differently if I turn it off, so I know its doing something.   Something just causes that "choose a default browser" slide up.  Strange....Anyway, still searching for a whitelist to tell it not to ask.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you disable all browsers. Make sure to keep in app browsing on. Cuz if it's if it will obviously ask for a browser (i know you did that, I'm just saying that that is not the issue. Otherwise I'm really unsure what's the deal.

Comment: Btw what phone do you have?

Comment: Yes, I did as you said, and in fact it does ask me what browser.   There must be something which is intercepting a call.   I just need to figure out what it is.  I am looking for a debugging tool which will intercept program launching and tell me what is calling the "browser" to load.  I have a Samsung AMP Prime with default software.