# How to prevent an application from opening links with an internal browser?

Tags: applications, default-applications, webview

**Background**

The situation is a little bit confusing but with try to explain:

I have 2 applications, A and B respectively.

Application A has some links which when clicked are supposed to open in application B (or use **external browser** in case application B isn't installed). This is the setup that I prefer as it doesn't use additional data since application B works offline fully.

However when application A updated, it no longer allows these links to open in application B (or external) browser, instead it has an **internal browser** which is limited and needs to use data to load the content which is inconvenient. I tried to communicate with the developer and sadly they said older applications were no longer supported hence I am stuck with application A with an internal browser.

Is there a way or workaround to at least force the app not to use its internal browser but allow for me to choose a preferred app or browser to open these links?

Comment: If the app A isn't firing an explicit intent to let the user choose the app to open with, I don't think you can do anything. There's no communication channel to intercept (not sure about some Xposed API hook though), developer is handling everything internally. You  may try to modify the app code in some way, if possible at all. // Is that in-app browser really internal and not a custom tab or webview?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like a custom tab, how to tell?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat How an app works can only be determined by reverse engineering (e.g. Jadx) or dynamic analysis (e.g. Frida). Both require Java and Android app development knowledge.

Comment: @Robert ok thanks I thought there was a quick way, just busy. I am familiar with reverse engineering though, will find some time to solve the puzzle, was just hoping it was as easy as intercepting or disabling the app's specific service(s)

Comment: If it is a Custom Tab, then my question might be related (though probably the answer might not be satisfying yet): [Prevent apps opening links in Chrome Custom Tabs (i.e. open in default browser directly)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145745/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks I think there are somewhat related, but no functional workaround yet to my particular issue

Comment: @AndrewT. the satisfying answer is just a small app (or a small feature) away: https://github.com/arunkumar9t2/lynket-browser/issues/139

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's an internal feature of application A which the developers fixed. Crude work around I suppose is to copy the link from application A, or the internal browser, and paste it to application B or external browser to view.

Comment: Well I a trying to build an automation task that intercepts Web View URL intent, and Launch browser app intent and point them to start an activity into app B android.intent.action.VIEW just hoping it works

Comment: If the 2 apps are relatively popular and in the list, perhaps you can try using Zappier:
https://zapier.com/apps